# How to get an correspondent id through a model on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I've trying to get the simple situation:

I have a Model called Company, inside Company I have companies and I have the following object: "state_id". I want to find the related companies that contain some id.

This is the only path that I can get the state_id. So, I am doing:

```
Company.all.each do |comp|
     comp.address.city.state_id
end
```

It works! But when I do:

```
Company.all.each do |comp|
     comp.address.city.state_id = 27
     #or comp.address.city.state_id(27)
end
```

it doesn't return the right data

I know that it simple, but unfortunately, I didn't getting the right output.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Company.joins(address: :city).where(cities: {state_id: 27})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked, how I didn't this before? haha thanks

Comment: my pleasure. I recommend you this guide about rails query interface https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks! I will check

Comment: @Diego please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it helped

Comment: Thanks @Vasilisa, now I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with `select` method. Also, don't mix up `==` and `=` - the former one checks equality and the latter one assigns a value:

```
needed_companies = Company.all.select do |comp|
     comp.address.city.state_id == 27
end
```

But it isn't a correct way, because you're loading all companies in memory and filtering it. Much better is to use SQL query (as in answer by Ursus) and return only needed companies from DB

Comment: Yeah, the == & = make sense to me. Thanks a lot